# Масштабирование яндекс карты через setBounds

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Делаю всё так:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('yamap', {
            center: [{{ $cityfull->coordinats }}],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({             
            clusterize: true,             
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });

    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    var url = window.location.href+'?json'; 
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    }).done(function(data) {         
        objectManager.add(data);        
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
    });  
}
```

> myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());

Не срабатывает, а точнее срабатывает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня работает: https://jsfiddle.net/fpqm78gt/ , надо посмотреть на ваши данные. Самым лучшим вариантом будет поправить пример выше чтобы начало воспроизводиться.

Comment: Ну я нашёл проблему. Карта в скрытом блоке находится. Поэтому собственно нужно было setBounds выполнять после её появления, но спасибо. Натолкнули на мысль искать в другом месте))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю, так как поисковик привел сюда, и это может оказаться полезным.

Была аналогичная ситуация - карта находится в скрытой вкладке. Комментарии к этому вопросу помогли решить и эту близкую проблему. В моем случае

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function (event, ui) {
    myMap.container.fitToViewport();
    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
});
```